# using iptables to filter vboxnet (virtualbox host only network)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, iptables

Im trying to use iptables to filter the traffic coming from a guest OS running on virtualbox.

The guest is configured to use a host only adapter for the network, and my Ubuntu host is configured to do IP forwarding, the guest can send and receive internet traffic.

Ip forwarding is setup on my host by adding the following lines to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1
```

So now I need to filter the traffic coming out of the guest OS, via vboxnet0 interface, 
For testing purposes I added the following rules to iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-LOG: " --log-level 4
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-LOG: " --log-level 4
```

Using this I can see the traffic from the web browser open on my Host OS, but upon closing the host web browser and visiting a site via the browser on my guest, the log file shows no traffic at all.

So, how do I filter my guest OS traffic via iptables on my host OS?